# "В напоминание нам" самодостаточно? О ком / о чём / кого / чего не требует, если контекст прозрачен?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

> У археологов прошлого века вошло в моду сохранять растения на их
>   привычных местах, отслеживать их рост и, в случае обнаружения в ранних
>   слоях зёрен или пыльцы, даже вновь засеивать древние улицы и площади
>   исконными травами, кустарниками и цветами. Но небольшая и прекрасная
>   роща, что стояла испокон веков на берегу Тибра, безо всякого спроса
>   сохранила несколько деревьев, словно **в напоминание нам**.

ПыСы. Я шапку подправила после укоризного коммента.

Comment: Последняя фраза у меня сомнений не вызывает, стоит как влитая.)

*>> Кого/что не требует?..* - Поясните, Галина, а то непонятно.

Comment: Лёш, вот приди и расскажи. *Кого/что* - это меня занесло слегка, может *о ком / о чём*? Что-то другое? Мне у "в напоминание" чего-то управляемого не хватает, а может, просто устала - перестала слышать текст.

Comment: *Сохранила... словно в напоминание нам.* -- всё тут совершенно в порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но небольшая и прекрасная роща, что стояла испокон веков на берегу Тибра, безо всякого спроса сохранила несколько деревьев, словно в напоминание нам **о прошедших временах.**

Формально существительное ***напоминание*** требует наличия существительного с предлогом О,ОБ (если оно не названо в контексте). Здесь вариант без существительного останавливает на себе внимание, кажется **стилистической неточностью.**

**НАПОМИНАНИЕ**, -я; ср. 1. к Напоминать (1 зн.). При напоминании о предстоящем докладе он нахмурился. 2. То, что заставляет вспомнить кого-, что-л. Букет сухих цветов - н. о лете.

Answer (score 0):

...на берегу Тибра, безо всякого спроса сохранила для нас несколько деревьев как живое послание.

Comment: Спасибо. Это мы поправили-переделали. А что было не так? Вот Niemand говорит: *Последняя фраза у меня сомнений не вызывает, стоит как влитая*.

Comment: Контекста нет, но напоминание-то требует развернуть мысль. Если серьёза нет, то и не надо искушать...

Comment: Как это "серьёза нет"?! О_о Два человека говорят мне диаметрально противоположные вещи, отчего вопрос посурьёзнел ваще непадеццки. 8-(

Comment: Напоминание о чём? Такой вопрос подспудно возникает. Пока нет ответа.

Comment: Может, и впрямь сама фраза не очень удачная, может, лучше было бы "в память", и вот тогда уж обязательно "о чем".